# TABLEAU: How do I find the average for each year?

Tags: tableau-prep

how do I find the average for each year's family income? it is from year 2000-2020.Thank you!

```
[2000 data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dliG.png)
[2001 data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH3gX.png)
[fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFOnv.png)
```

I tried using AVG however the field says that aggregated functions are only supposed when included in a level of detail expression.

Comment: Can you post the text in the pictures as text (text is better readable than those pictures)?  And, please tell us, how did you try to use the AVG function ?

Answer (score 0):

you can load the data in Prep and use the Aggregate operation :

[image]